# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

cs-training.csv is like:

```
+----+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
|    | SeriousDlqin2yrs | RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines | age | NumberOfTime30-59DaysPastDueNotWorse |  DebtRatio  | MonthlyIncome | NumberOfOpenCreditLinesAndLoans | NumberOfTimes90DaysLate | NumberRealEstateLoansOrLines | NumberOfTime60-89DaysPastDueNotWorse | NumberOfDependents |
+----+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
|  1 |                1 |                          0.766126609 |  45 |                                    2 | 0.802982129 | 9120          |                              13 |                       0 |                            6 |                                    0 | 2                  |
|  2 |                0 |                          0.957151019 |  40 |                                    0 | 0.121876201 | 2600          |                               4 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | 1                  |
|  3 |                0 |                           0.65818014 |  38 |                                    1 | 0.085113375 | 3042          |                               2 |                       1 |                            0 |                                    0 | 0                  |
|  4 |                0 |                          0.233809776 |  30 |                                    0 | 0.036049682 | 3300          |                               5 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | 0                  |
|  5 |                0 |                            0.9072394 |  49 |                                    1 | 0.024925695 | 63588         |                               7 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 | 0                  |
|  6 |                0 |                          0.213178682 |  74 |                                    0 | 0.375606969 | 3500          |                               3 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 | 1                  |
|  7 |                0 |                          0.305682465 |  57 |                                    0 |        5710 | NA            |                               8 |                       0 |                            3 |                                    0 | 0                  |
|  8 |                0 |                          0.754463648 |  39 |                                    0 | 0.209940017 | 3500          |                               8 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | 0                  |
|  9 |                0 |                          0.116950644 |  27 |                                    0 |          46 | NA            |                               2 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | NA                 |
| 10 |                0 |                          0.189169052 |  57 |                                    0 | 0.606290901 | 23684         |                               9 |                       0 |                            4 |                                    0 | 2                  |
| 11 |                0 |                          0.644225962 |  30 |                                    0 |  0.30947621 | 2500          |                               5 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | 0                  |
| 12 |                0 |                           0.01879812 |  51 |                                    0 |  0.53152876 | 6501          |                               7 |                       0 |                            2 |                                    0 | 2                  |
| 13 |                0 |                          0.010351857 |  46 |                                    0 | 0.298354075 | 12454         |                              13 |                       0 |                            2 |                                    0 | 2                  |
| 14 |                1 |                          0.964672555 |  40 |                                    3 | 0.382964747 | 13700         |                               9 |                       3 |                            1 |                                    1 | 2                  |
| 15 |                0 |                          0.019656581 |  76 |                                    0 |         477 | 0             |                               6 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 | 0                  |
| 16 |                0 |                          0.548458062 |  64 |                                    0 | 0.209891754 | 11362         |                               7 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 | 2                  |
| 17 |                0 |                          0.061086118 |  78 |                                    0 |        2058 | NA            |                              10 |                       0 |                            2 |                                    0 | 0                  |
| 18 |                0 |                          0.166284079 |  53 |                                    0 |  0.18827406 | 8800          |                               7 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | 0                  |
| 19 |                0 |                          0.221812771 |  43 |                                    0 | 0.527887839 | 3280          |                               7 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 | 2                  |
| 20 |                0 |                          0.602794411 |  25 |                                    0 | 0.065868263 | 333           |                               2 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 | 0                  |
| 21 |                0 |                          0.200923382 |  43 |                                    0 | 0.430046338 | 12300         |                              10 |                       0 |                            2 |                                    0 | 0                  |
+----+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# using RF to predict and fill null
def set_missing(df):
    process_df = df.ix[:,[5,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]]
    known = process_df[process_df.MonthlyIncome.notnull()].as_matrix()
    unknown = process_df[process_df.MonthlyIncome.isnull()].as_matrix()
    X = known[:, 1:]
    y = known[:, 0]
    rfr = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0, n_estimators=200,max_depth=3,n_jobs=-1)
    rfr.fit(X,y)
    predicted = rfr.predict(unknown[:, 1:]).round(0)
    print(predicted)
    # fill null,and this line goes wrong
    df.loc[(df.MonthlyIncome.isnull()), 'MonthlyIncome'] = predicted
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = pd.read_csv('cs-training.csv')
    data.describe().to_csv('DataDescribe.csv')
    data=set_missing(data)
    data=data.dropna()
    data = data.drop_duplicates()
    data.to_csv('MissingData.csv',index=False)
    data.describe().to_csv('MissingDataDescribe.csv')
```

I haved checked pages about "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')",however mine seems like a different case.May someone know why and how to fix kindly help.thank!

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 data=set_missing(data)
>
> in set_missing(df)
>        13     rfr.fit(X,y)
>        14 
>   ---> 15     predicted = rfr.predict(unknown[:, 1:]).round(0)
>        16     print(predicted)
>        17
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in
>   predict(self, X)
>       683         """
>       684         # Check data
>   --> 685         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
>       686 
>       687         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in
>   _validate_X_predict(self, X)
>       353                                  "call `fit` before exploiting the model.")
>       354 
>   --> 355         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
>       356 
>       357     @property
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in
>   _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
>       363 
>       364         if check_input:
>   --> 365             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
>       366             if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or
>       367                                 X.indptr.dtype != np.intc):
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
>   check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       405                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
>       406         if force_all_finite:
>   --> 407             _assert_all_finite(array)
>       408 
>       409     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
>   _assert_all_finite(X)
>        56             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
>        57         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
>   ---> 58                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
>        59 
>        60
>
> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

Comment: The column 'MonthlyIncome' contains value 'NA' - your code does not seem to handle that.

Comment: There are NA values in your dataframe.

Comment: @Juliusz I need to predict it,so it contains NA?